# No files included in stash exception

Tags: exception, logging, jenkins, groovy, hudson

I am using `stash` command in `groovy` script. I am getting:

```
Caught: hudson.AbortException: No files included in stash
```

However the logs before the exception says:

```
Stashed 1 file(s)
[Pipeline] stash
Stashed 1 file(s)
```

can you please advise

Comment: Can you edit your title to make it more concise?

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing based on your log you're doing more than one stash, perhaps you do have one that doesn't have any files, in that case you need `allowEmpty: true`

```
stash allowEmpty: true, includes: 'foo', name: 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I was making a mistake by specifying multiple files by name without comma separator. Correct way is:

```
stash includes: "a.bin,a.log", name: "<name>"
```

Please use "Pipeline Syntax" link to generate command and read description of fields you want to use.